# Is this population growth algorithm accurate?

Tags: lua

For fun, I made Lua script that'd simulate the growth rate of the fictional species 'krogan' from the game Mass Effect. They can live for 1,000 years and one krogan female can give birth 1,000 krogan in a year. The basic rules are:

1. A member of the population only dies at year 1001
2. 50% of the population between ages 100 and 300 are fertile women
3. 4% of fertile krogan women are pregnant each year
4. Pregnant krogan give birth to 1,000 kids each year

The code (and output) can be found [HERE](http://ideone.com/f2QA64). Otherwise...

```
local NumYears = 1000 --How many years to estimate
local MinFertile = 100 --Age krogan start reproducing
local MaxFertile = 300 --Age krogan stop reproducing
local KroganAge = 1000 --How old a krogan can get
local Start_Population = 100000 --Number of initial krogans
local TimeSkips = 10 --Population updates displayed every # years
local Fertility = 1000 --Number of average children born by one mother each year
local PercentPregnant = 0.04 --percent of population pregnant during the year

math.randomseed(os.time())

local Krogans = {}

do --randomizes current krogan population
    local sum = 0
    for i = 1, KroganAge do
        local x = i-KroganAge/2
        x = x*5/KroganAge
        Krogans[i] = math.exp(-((x)^2)/2)/math.sqrt(2*math.pi) --bell curve
        sum = sum + Krogans[i]
    end

    --So that the ratio remains the same, and the total sum is around Start_Population
    local left = 0
    for i = 1, KroganAge do
        local a = Krogans[i]/sum*Start_Population
        left = left + (a-math.floor(a))
        local extra = math.floor(left)
        Krogans[i] = math.floor(a)+extra
        left = left - extra
    end
end


function NextYear()
    local Fertile = 0
    local Population = 0
    for i = MinFertile, MaxFertile do
        if Krogans[i] then
            Fertile = Fertile + Krogans[i]*0.5 --mult by 0.5 for fertile females (50% of population)
        end
    end
    for i = KroganAge, 2, -1 do
        if Krogans[i-1] then
            Krogans[i] = Krogans[i-1] --advance krogan by one year
            Population = Population + Krogans[i] --get population count
        end
    end
    Krogans[1] = Fertile*Fertility*PercentPregnant --Krogan born this year
    Population = Population + Krogans[1]
    return Fertile, Population
end

local words = {} --Table used for output formatting 
words[9] = "Billion"
words[12] = "Trillion"
words[15] = "Quadrillion"
words[18] = "Quintillion"
words[21] = "Sextillion"
words[24] = "Septillion"
words[27] = "Octillion"
words[30] = "Nonillion"
words[33] = "Decillion"
words[36] = "Undecillion"
words[39] = "Duodecillion"
words[42] = "Tredecillion"
words[45] = "Quattuordecillion"
words[48] = "Quindecillion"

function convert(n) --Converts/formats numbers into easy-to-read output
    if n <= 999999999 then -- credit http://r...content-available-to-author-only...n.it
        local left,num,right = string.match(n,'^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')
        return left..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,'):reverse())..right
    else
        n = string.format("%18.0f",n):gsub("%s","")
        local digits = #n-1
        local choice = math.floor(digits/3)*3
        local num = (digits-choice)+1
        local str = string.sub(n,1,num).."."..string.sub(n,num+1,num+1).." "..words[choice]
        return str
    end
end

for i = 1, NumYears do
    local Fertile, Population = NextYear()
    if i%TimeSkips == 0 then
        print("Year: "..i)
        print("Total Population:\t"..convert(math.floor(Population)))
        print("Fertile Females: \t"..convert(math.floor(Fertile)))
        print("----")
    end
end
```

This predictably results in a rather large population after a few hundred years. My question is, does this reflect accurate krogan populations assuming all death is from old age? I tried to input a range of numbers for humans (fertile between ages 15 and 44, max age 70, and 1 child born per pregnancy), but it just results in a *declining* population, and I'm not sure why.

I'm guessing it has something to do with how the number of children born each year is calculated. It's pretty simple multiplication:

```
Krogans[1] = Fertile*Fertility*PercentPregant
--[[
    Fertile: Number of Fertile Women
    Fertility: Number of children born in a pregnancy
    PercentPregnant: How many fertile women are pregnant this year (4% = 0.04)
]]
```

But is there anything wrong with this? Why does this result in a declining population?

Comment: "*Why does this result in*" Result in what?

Comment: why do you think your population should grow?
you just picked random numbers. use 5% fertility and it will grow...
You have a decline because more death ratio is higher than birth ratio at 4% fertility. (in your model)  that's it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about mathematics.